# Push results from MYSQL Query into an Array

Tags: php, arrays, function, if-statement, foreach

I'm having trouble with the function below. Basically what it is supposed to do is check IF each item from the array (`$idDiscontinuedArray`) it's discontinued value from its respective table (either `1` or `0`).

Now I’m not sure to push these answers in an array to make the next part more simpler. At the moment the its spits `$rows` out individually.

The result is: `Array ( [discontinued] => 1, ) Array ( [discontinued] => 1 ) Array ( [discontinued] => 0 ) Array ( [discontinued] => 0 ) Array ( [discontinued] => 1 )....` where I would rather have `Array [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 1....`

The next part of the script is to check and see whether that ALL `$rows = 1` which means end of script. If this is not the case this will run the function `changeDiscontinued($dbh, $id, $idDiscontinuedArray)`.

```
function checkDiscontinued($dbh, $idDiscontinuedArray) {
try {
    foreach ($idDiscontinuedArray as $id) {
        $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT discontinued FROM `$id` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");
        $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($rows);
        }
        if $rows['discontinued'] == TRUE) { 
            //echo $id . "Action if true";
        } else {
            changeDiscontinued($dbh, $id, $idDiscontinuedArray);
            echo $id . "Items already discontinued!";
            }       
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: your $id variable in your else statement will always be the last value in your $idDiscontinuedArray, is that your intent?  what is changeDiscontinued() supposed to do?

Comment: You're using $id for the table name, is that what you're intending to do?

Comment: Can someone say SQL Injection Vulnerabilities big time? You are already using PDO, prepare that statement...

Comment: What do you mean Justin? Care to share?

Comment: see answer below. See Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrect_type_handling

Comment: [can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter][1] The answer is no.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Did not test this code, but it goes over prepared statements, and how to push items into an array. If you want more help, we can go into chat.

```
$discont = array();

function checkDiscontinued($dbh, $idDiscontinuedArray) {
try {
    foreach ($idDiscontinuedArray as $id) {
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT discontinued FROM $id ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");
        $stmt = $sql->execute(array($id));
        $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($rows);
        }
        if $rows['discontinued'] == TRUE) { 
            //echo $id . "Action if true";
        } else {
            changeDiscontinued($dbh, $id, $idDiscontinuedArray);
            echo $id . "Items already discontinued!";
            array_push($doscont, $id);
            }       
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this worked for you, don't forget to mark it is the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - i get the error - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''19474' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Try putting back-ticks around the ?, i.e. `?` in the sql statement.

Comment: Got it to work just because $id was not an array, it is a single number and the foreach loop handles the different id's. Now answer retrieved is false when the mysql table is in fact true.